# Generate view queries using a loop

Tags: postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL query where I have 2x `$i` in a bash-like notation to make it comprehensible that I want to print out a number `i` ranging from 0 to 20 at these positions using a for loop. Briefly, the idea is to generate some SQL code as a temp table that I can dump to a file. Which file is then executed to actually run these queries.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "',
    table_name, '_factor', $i,
    '" AS SELECT id, POWER(2,', $i,') AS factor ',
    'FROM "', table_name, '" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;'
)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%^prefix%'
  AND table_name NOT LIKE '%suffix$'
  AND table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Notice also that this `SELECT` statement already loops over N tables.

From what I've read so far, this would be the kind of structure in which to embed my code:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..20 LOOP
        -- insert the previous query here
    RAISE NOTICE 'factor number is: %', i;
    END LOOP;
END; $$
```

But when I do so and actually execute it, I got this error message:

```sql
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

And if I replace `SELECT` by `PERFORM`, I end up with a single word "DO" dumped in my file.

How could I generate all my queries using a for loop?

Resulting queries should look like:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_0" AS SELECT id, 1 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_1" AS SELECT id, 2 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_20" AS SELECT id, 1048576 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_0" AS SELECT id, 1 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_1" AS SELECT id, 2 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_20" AS SELECT id, 1048576 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
```

Precisions: I store this SQL statement in a `/sql_queries/generate_views_queries.sql` file and execute it to dump the resulting queries in an other file `/sql_queries/do_create_views.sql`:

```bash
psql -d "host=${HOST} port=${PORT} dbname=${POSTGRES_DB} user=${POSTGRES_USER} password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}" \
  -f "/sql_queries/generate_views_queries.sql" \
  -t --output="/sql_queries/do_create_views.sql"
```

PG version is 13.1 from the official PostgreSQL [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=13.).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly below anonymous block should do it.

```
DO $$
declare 

tabs cursor for
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%^prefix%'
  AND table_name NOT LIKE '%suffix$'
  AND table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name;
rec record;

query_statement text;
BEGIN

open tabs;
loop
fetch tabs into rec;

exit when not found;

    FOR i IN 0..20 LOOP
         
    query_statement:= 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "'||rec.table_name||'_factor'||i||'" AS SELECT id, POWER(2,'||i||') AS factor FROM "'||rec.table_name||'" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;';
    RAISE NOTICE '%' , query_statement;
    RAISE NOTICE 'factor number is: %', i;
    END LOOP;
end loop;
END; $$
```

Comment: edited my answer. Try again please.

Comment: Thanks. I still have a simple "DO" in the resulting file (I've edited the question to actually include how I run the SQL). But commands are actually printed to stdout with a `NOTICE:  ` decoration in front of them.

Comment: If you want to execute command add  execute query_statement;  in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up!

I've investigated in the direction of a fully fledged PL/pgSQL function, and here's what I've ended with, which is working up to a single unwanted header row:

`./sql_queries/generate_views_queries.sql`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_view_queries()
    RETURNS SETOF text -- this did the trick !
AS
$$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..20 LOOP
        RETURN QUERY SELECT CONCAT(
            'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "',
            table_name, '_factor', $i,
            '" AS SELECT id, POWER(2,', $i,') AS factor ',
            'FROM "', table_name, '" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;'
        )
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name LIKE '%^prefix%'
          AND table_name NOT LIKE '%suffix$'
          AND table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
          AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        ORDER BY table_name;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT public.generate_view_queries();
```

Then, when calling it using `psql` like:

```sh
psql -d "host=${HOST} port=${PORT} dbname=${POSTGRES_DB} user=${POSTGRES_USER} password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}" \
    -f ./sql_queries/generate_view_queries.sql \
    -t --output=./sql_queries/do_create_views.sql:
```

it returns the `./sql_queries/do_create_views.sql` file with the following desired content:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_0" AS SELECT id, 1 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_1" AS SELECT id, 2 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefix1_table_20" AS SELECT id, 1048576 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_0" AS SELECT id, 1 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_1" AS SELECT id, 2 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "prefixN_table_20" AS SELECT id, 1048576 AS factor FROM "prefix_table" WHERE factor IS NOT NULL;
```

I only have to call `sed` after to clean this first row which comes from 'I don't know where' (it sounds like the success message of the function creation):

```sh
sed -i 's/CREATE FUNCTION//g' ./create_views.sql
```

Information about the `SETOF` return type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET